# how to link to sharepoint 2010 edit form directly in email

Tags: email, list-form

Is it possible to go to the edit view of an sharepoint 2010 list item directly from email? I have a workflow that sends an email to a user to edit a list item. The link -at this time- takes them to the list. I would like for the link to take them to the edit view of that item.
thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

http://path/nameoflist/Forms/EditForm.aspx?ID=IDofitem

where 
Path: path of the site
nameoflist : the name of your list
IDofitem : unique id of item

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

There is cleaner solution using **copyutil**:

http://weblogs.asp.net/jan/archive/2008/02/26/copyutil-aspx-a-little-sharepoint-gem.aspx

Just change action to "editform" and you will be redirected to editform.

Why is this solution better? You don't have to merge string to get the URL and you use internal SP mechanism.

Also when you change your default forms you don't have to change the generated url - copyutil will handle it for you.